# HTML List Design Like Word - Tabs

Tags: html, list, formatting

I'm currently struggling to implement a list in HTML which looks like this.

[image: Word Screenshot]

The important thing for me would be the tab stops obviously. I tried to look for it online, however I'm not native to English and I do not know how you would call the formatting of a list like that.

Kind Regards,
Vincenz

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what are you looking for?

Are you trying to do a list like this?
You sure can add more arrows and all the thigns that you can see here.
I have added the arrows in icon fonts, I have not edited it exactly like in your example, because I don't know what exactly do you need.

```css
.list {
    display: inline;
}

.list p {
    display: inline;
}

.year {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.arrow {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.text {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>
                <p class="year">1985 - 1986</p>
                <ion-icon class="arrow" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                <p class="text">Studien aufhenthalt....</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="year">1985 - 1986</p>
                <ion-icon class="arrow" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                <p class="text">Studien aufhenthalt....</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p class="year">1985 - 1986</p>
                <ion-icon class="arrow" name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
                <p class="text">Studien aufhenthalt....</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.2.3/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

sure it doesen't look like your example, but you can edit it like you want.
[image]

Comment: Hi sorry if I wasn't clear enough! I'm looking for a way, that basically the text written after the year numbers and a text that follows, like in the second bullet point, are on the same level. So when you look in the line of 1987-1994, Jacinta starts in the same "tab" like the line below, which starts with "Lehre". 
So I'm trying to make a list where the text is indented the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really understand the image, but I assume you want something like this

[image: Example]

You can do this, using this workaround (no CSS or JS)

Nest another UL inside the list

EXAMPLE:

```
<ul>
<li>
List Item 1
</li>
<ul>
Sub Item 1
</ul>
</ul>
```

You can view the full JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aarav123/xbLty4as/3/)